# Combine two array with index number

Tags: arrays

I have 2 arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => bedroom
    [1] => traditional
    [2] => farmhouse
    [3] => modern
    [4] => contemporary
)
```

and

```
Array
(
    [0] => aaaa
    [1] => bbbb
    [2] => cccc
    [3] => dddd
    [4] => eeee
    )
```

How can I combine the two arrays above, I want the result in a **String** like this...

```
bedroom_aaaa, traditional_bbbb, farmhouse_cccc, modern_dddd, contemporary_eee
```

So far I tried like this, but it does not work...

```
$res = array_combine ($a,$b);

                foreach($res as $r){
                  echo $res.'_'.$r.', ';
                }
```

Comment: Is this php? If so you should add that language tag to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your logic i found the way... Thanks

```
        if(count($a)==count($b)){
            for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
                $res = $a[$i]." _ ".$b[$i];
                echo $res.'<br />';
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This php function takes two arrays as input and checks if they have the same size. If the two arrays don't have same size then there will be error "undefined index".

```
function combine_array($a,$b){
    $res = [];
    if(count($a)==count($b)){
      // The count function returns the size of an array
      for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
        $res[$i] = $a[$i]."_".$b[$i];
      }
      return $res;
    }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for trying help... your code get error result... on here '$res = [];'

Parse error: syntax error,

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and readers need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: @AdhyKunKun I don't think there is an error I have tried it out. else you can add $res = array(); But anyways the problem is solved.